# Etymology of "settee"?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I was reading Cochrane's *Memoirs of a Fighting Captain* when I came across this:-

> However, at 3.00pm, as a large settee was running into the mole of Ciotat, we discharged two shots at her, which went over and fell into the town.

I was momentarily disconcerted by the notion of *[a seat, for two or more people, with a back and usually with arms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/settee)* sailing around the Mediterranean, pursued by Cochrane's frigate, but I persisted and turned up *[a vessel with a very long, sharp prow, carrying two or three masts with lateen sails](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/settee)*, which makes rather more sense.

This leads me to wonder why a *settee* (the vessel) is so-called. Its name can't surely be connected with the item of furniture, can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are probably unrelated. The ship came first in the 16th century and is from Italian *saettia*, is possibly from *saetta*, arrow. The furniture is from the 18th century and possibly from *settle*.

---

The *OED* has three definitions for *settee*. The [first](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176845?rskey=o3Dh1S&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) is the vessel, an earliest quotation from 1587, and is now historical:

> **Forms:**  15 **settea,** 16 **sattie, satty, satia, sett(y)e,** 16–17 **sattee,** 17 **cettee, saetia, setye,** 16– **settee.**
>
> **Etymology:**  < Italian *saettia* (pronounced /-ˈtia/ ), ‘a very speedie pinnace’ (Florio 1598), of obscure origin, commonly viewed as < *saetta* arrow. Compare French *scétie, setie, scitie*.
>
> A decked vessel, with a long sharp prow, carrying two or three masts with a kind of lateen sails, in use in the Mediterranean.

(The [second](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176846?rskey=o3Dh1S&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid), of unknown origin and rarely observed, is first quoted in 1688 and means "A double pinner for the head.")

The [third](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176847?rskey=o3Dh1S&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid), first quoted in 1716, is the furniture:

> **Etymology:**  perhaps a fanciful variation of settle n.1: see -ee *suffix*2.
>
> A seat (for indoors) holding two or more persons, with a back and (usually) arms; occasionally also with divisions.

Comment: Here is a modern usage of [settee sail](http://www.raphaelfreire.com/sailing-management/the-settee-rig.html)

Comment: @Henry: The OED has a *settee sail* quote from 1794.

Comment: Indeed.  But my point was about whether the sail meaning was just historical

Comment: @Henry: The OED says the vessel meaning is historical, not the sail (if I'm reading it right). It's possible the name came from the arrow-shaped, long, sharp prow, but its [lateen sails](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/58500/58548/58548_settee.htm) are also quite arrow-shaped.

Comment: Conrad's novel *The Arrow of Gold* features a settee (used by gunrunners), so presumably he believed in the *saetta* theory.

Comment: Also, Henry's answer is actually a fourth meaning, which is certainly not obsolete; there was a recent quote in a sailing magazine (which I can't source, dammit) to the effect that 'A settee is the Western Mediterranean term for a rig that in the Eastern Med would be a shortened lateen, and in Scotland's Western Isles would be a lengthened lugsail; in neither setting would it be out of place'.